# Simple SQL (hopefully!) Query Question

Tags: sql, mysql

I hope someone can help me with my faltering steps to formulate a SQL query for the following problem.

I have a simple table that records visitor names and dates. The relationship is many to many, in that for any given date there are many visitors, and for any given visitor there will be one or more dates (i.e. repeat visits). There is a complicating third column that records the name of the exhibit(s) the visitor interacted with. The data might look like this:

```
NAME     ART            DATE
Joe      Picture 1      23-1-09
Joe      Picture 2      23-1-09
Joe      Picture 3      23-1-09
Janet    Picture 2      23-1-09
Joe      Picture 2      31-2-09
```

I want to know what the distribution of single and multiple visits are, in other words, how many people only visited once, how many people visited on 2 separate days, how many on 3 separate days, and so on.

Can anyone help please? Thank you in anticipation!

Frankie

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the code you have written so far? People don't generally like to just write your code for you...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME, COUNT(ART) as num_exhibits, COUNT(DATE) as num_days 
FROM table GROUP BY NAME;
```

This will give you a table of each name along with the total number of visits for that name and the total number of dates visited.

To get an average exhibit per date you can do:

```
SELECT 
    NAME,
    COUNT(ART) as num_exhibits,
    COUNT(DATE) as num_days,
    (num_exhibits / num_days) as avg_exhibit_per_day
FROM table GROUP BY NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to count the total number of distinct visits, including multiple visits on the same date, you could use:

```
SELECT [Name],
COUNT(*) AS Count_Dates
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [Name]
```

However, if you don't want to count multiple visits on the same date, you could use the following:

```
SELECT [Name],
COUNT(*) AS Count_Dates
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [Name],
    [Date]
    FROM MyTable
) a
GROUP BY [Name]
```

This will show you the distribution of total people who visited x times per day. However, this will not display numbers for counts where 0 people visited that many times - for example, if nobody visited 8 times, then there won't be a row for Count_Dates = 8. If you did want to display a full list from 0-10 visits, you could create a temp table of Count_Dates and insert values from 0-10, then use it as part of the main query.

```
SELECT Count_Dates,
COUNT(*) AS Count_Visitors
FROM (SELECT [Name], COUNT(DISTINCT [Date]) AS Count_Dates FROM MyTable GROUP BY [Name]) a
GROUP BY Count_Dates
ORDER BY Count_Dates
```

Comment: Thanks all but only Flayto understands what I'm after. How many people visited twice, how many people visited 3 times, 4 times, etc? One would expect most people to visit once and a diminishing number to visit at the higer number of times.

Flayto, transposing your second example into the actual values used in my database I get :

SELECT avatar, COUNT(*) AS Count_Dates FROM(SELECT DISTINCT avatar, date FROM artbox) GROUP BY avatar;

And the error message that results says:

#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias 

Can you throw any light on this please? Thank you.

Comment: The subquery in brackets must have an alias - in my example I added the letter "a" after the closing parentheses. I can't remember if in MySQL you need to use the "AS" keyword - try adding just an alias, and if that doesn't work, add "AS" before the alias name.

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT Date) would save the sub-query.

Comment: Thank you both. Although the query operates now it doesn't yield the desired result. What I am after is something like the following:

DAYS VISITED / NUMBER OF PEOPLE WHO VISITED THAT MANY TIMES
1 / 2340
2/ 983
3 / 502
4 / 128
5 / 63
6 / 14
7 / 8
8 / 0
9 / 0
10 / 2

i.e. This tells me that for example only 2 people were crazy enough to visit this place 10 times. This is the sort of data I am trying to extract. The query above gives me number of times visited per person, whereas I am trying to plot how may people visit x many ttimes. Sorry if my initial description was ambiguous!